# Why Mindray BC3600 asking for coldfire login and password when connecting to LIS?

Tags: authentication, lis

We are developing LIS for Mindray BC 3600. When we are connecting to the analyser it is asking for **"coldfire login:"** and **password**. But neither the suppliers nor service center know what it is. Is there anybody who encountered such problem and solved it? If there is please help us.

Comment: Your tags are incorrect: "lis" is for "lognest increasing subsequence" and "authentification" is kinda broad. Personally I have no idea what LIS in your question stands for. Please add some details and proper tags to attract the right person.

Comment: Sorry for that. It stands for Laboratory Information System. Or it can be referred as LIMS. Mindray BC3600 is actually medical equipment, analyser. And we are developing a software to communicate with it.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded rude. I'm unable to find the right tags for your case, it seems very specific and not discussed on StackOverflow yet. If i were you, I'd try to ask that question on some more specific forum. Good luck looking for answer!

Comment: Not at all Denis. It's okay.. And thank you for your advice. I think you're right because me too could not find any like questions here in Stackoverflow.